# Eigenvalues of exp(tA)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question that reads:

Find the eigenvalues of $\exp(tA)$, which is defined by the convergent Taylor series.

$$ \exp(tA) = I +tA + \frac{t^2}{2!}  A^2 +\cdots +\frac{t^n}{n!}  A^n+ \cdots =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n A^n}{n!}$$

where $I$ is an identity matrix and $t$ is a real parameter.

This is my answer:

$A = PDP^{-1}$.

Hence it becomes addition of the eigenvalues and this addition of eigenvalues is actually is a geometric progression.

So the solution is $I(1-(tD/n)^n)/(1-tD/n)$.

Not sure whether I am correct.

Comment: Your sum should an infinite series, right ?

Comment: yes.. that is right..

Comment: Hint: triangularize $A$.

Comment: Did you willingly stop at degree $n$ because $A$ is nilpotent?

Comment: If you're looking for eigenvalues then the solution can not be a matrix. Furthermore, since we deal with an infinite series, your result can not depend on $n$ (if $n$ is your index for summation).

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Do the triangularization of the matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and use the fact that $\left(PDP^{-1}\right)^n = PD^nP^{-1}$. You should get that the spectrum of $\exp(tA)$ is the set $\left\{ \exp(t\lambda), \lambda\in \text{sp}(A) \right\}$ where $\text{sp}(A)$ is the spectrum of A.